# Javascript create selection on element in memory, not in dom

Tags: javascript, testing, selection

I've been experimenting with selection and ranges in JS, and I was interested in writing some test scripts related to this. For instance, looking at contentEditables, I'd like to write tests that show how the markup generated by `execCommand` interacts with other markup already in the editable container.

Let's say I have a document like this:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <p id="test">Hello World</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Now, I could select "Hello" programatically like this:

```
p = document.getElementById('test');
r = document.createRange();
r.setStart(p.firstChild,0);
r.setEnd(p.firstChild,5);
s = window.getSelection();
s.removeAllRanges();
s.addRange(r);
```

I can run execCommand or anything else that requires a selection against this, so it's all good. However, it seems I can't do this against an element created in memory only. For instance:

```
p = document.createElement('p');
p.innerText = "Hello World";
r = document.createRange();
r.setStart(p.firstChild,0);
r.setEnd(p.firstChild,5);
s = window.getSelection();
s.removeAllRanges();
s.addRange(r);
```

This no longer works. `r.toString()` would return `"Hello"`, but after `s.addRange(r)`, `s.rangeCount` would return `0`.

For purposes of testing functions that operate on the selection, it would be nice to be able to create an element, make a selection, run the function, and compare the result to the expected output without needing to add and remove elements to the DOM in order to test them.

I'm guessing part of the issue is the selection doesn't want to accept a range that is not inside the DOM. [MDN implies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection) that `window.getSelection()` is not the only way to create a selection object...

> Selection is the class of the object returned by window.getSelection()
>   *and other methods*.

... but it doesn't provide any further information about how else you can create these, or if selections can be created on in memory objects.

Is there a better way to do this that I'm overlooking, or some known workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you have to add your elements to the DOM for the selection to work. It's a shame: I'd like  to avoid violating the DOM in [Rangy](http://code.google.com/p/rangy)'s feature tests but can't, and have had a few bugs to deal with as a result.

There was a related thread on the WHATWG mailing list a couple of years ago. I don't think anything came of it.

http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-webapps/2012JanMar/0159.html

Comment: Thanks for the info, Tim. Do you happen to know about the Selection object - MDN implies there are other methods besides window.getSelection() that return it but you can't instantiate it directly, what is the MDN documentation referring to?

Comment: @Andrew: I don't know. There is also `document.getSelection()`, which is an alias of the same method of `window`, but I don't think there's another way of getting the selection that's accessible from a web page. Maybe there are other methods in Mozilla that are available to extensions.